# Remove Duplicate Strings | Regex | Pattern Matcher

Tags: java, android, string

I'm fairly new to programming in Java, still learning. I've successfully removed "?" out of the url's im capturing via regex. However, the website I'm pulling images from has multiple instances of the image with the same name thus returning duplicate strings.

How can I remove the duplicate strings?

My code for capturing the images and names from the website:

String result = null;

```
    try {
        result = task.execute("https://www.therichest.com/top-lists/top-100-richest-celebrities").get();
        String[] splitResult = result.split("<div class='wp-pagenavi'>");

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("srcset=\"(.*?)\\?q");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(splitResult[0]);


        while (m.find()) {
            celebURLs.add(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }

        p = Pattern.compile("alt=\'(.*?)Net");
        m = p.matcher(splitResult[0]);

        while(m.find()) {
            celebNames.add(m.group(1));
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to stick all the names in a Set, then walk the set when you're done.  The functionality of a set will filter out the dupes.